# Using jQuery load function against the window scrollbar to retrieve new data from mysql db

Tags: jquery

I am refreshing a div element to get the latest chat message with the scrollbar being programmed to scroll to bottom to see new message.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 chatLoader"></div>
```

Here is the function doing that but I cannot scroll up to check other messages, the scrollbar keep scrolling down

```
var loader = setInterval(
    function(){
        $(".chatLoader").load("./chatData.php").each(function(){

        }).fadeIn(400, function(){
            $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this)[0].clientHeight);
        })
},1500);
```

Is there a way to correct this behaviour?

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, you just need to save the old value of scrollHeight and then compare with that before you scroll:

```
var oldScrollHeight = 0;
var loader = setInterval(
    function(){
        $(".chatLoader").load("./chatData.php").each(function(){
        }).fadeIn(400, function(){
            if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight > oldscrollHeight)
            {
                $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this)[0].clientHeight);
            }
            oldscrollHeight = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
        })
},1500);
```

Now you should be able to scroll up UNTIL a new message arrives, then it will scroll to the Bottom. Hope that's what you want.
Edit: I have the initial oldscrollHeight to 0 (zero). The function then sets a new value every time it has processed.

Comment: Okay thanks. How do I get the oldscrollHeight? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Before scroll you should make a condition.

With this code if you are two messages from the last messages it does not going to scroll to the bottom.

```
var loader = setInterval(
    function(){
        $(".chatLoader").load("./chatData.php").each(function(){

        }).fadeIn(400, function(){
            var messages = $(".chatLoader");
            var newMessage = messages.children("li:last-child");

            var clientHeight = messages.prop("clientHeight");
            var scrollTop = messages.prop("scrollTop");
            var scrollHeight = messages.prop("scrollHeight");

            var messageHeight = newMessage.innerHeight();
            var lastMessageHeight = newMessage.prev().innerHeight();

           if(clientHeight  + messageHeight + lastMessageHeight + scrollTop >= scrollHeight){
               messages.scrollTop(scrollHeight);
            }

        })
},1500);
```

Comment: Would this be a new function block or replace this line   `$(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this)[0].clientHeight);`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your scenario!

You should add a `position: fixed` part to bottom of your page.

I think you yourself are now guessing the new scenario!

```
.fixed-part{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: visible;
    border-top: solid 2px #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Now, you must add per new message to it **and** to your previous panel both.
You can minimize this part when scroll to top and open it when new message receives.